# Rerender DOM in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations

I'm using some CSS Animations in my React app, but I'm having issues with only some of the nodes animating because the rest are not being rerendered, but rather are being recycled in the render function. Because of this they don't show the CSS animation as expected. Is there any way to force React to re-render the nodes instead of reusing them?

Comment: CSS Animations shouldn't be dependant of rendering nodes. But if your case requires it, then you can use `this.forceUpdate();` to re-render component.

Comment: The CSS animation I'm using only has an iteration-count of 1, i.e. it only happens the first time the node is loaded into the DOM. 
Across renders, React seems to reuse the nodes so the animation doesn't run again. I'll try `this.forceUpdate()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS animations depend on changes in class or style. For your animations to happen, you need to change any of these, which will force react to re-render anyway. So I do not expect `this.forceUpdate()` to make a difference.

In lists, react re-uses components (e.g. if you reorder items in a list). E.g. if you have a list:

```
<li>1. Cat</li>
<li>2. Mouse</li>
<li>3. Dog</li>
```

And you reorder them to:

```
<li>2. Mouse</li>
<li>1. Cat</li>
<li>3. Dog</li>
```

React will by default NOT exchange the `<li>` items. But change the text inside the `<li>` items (because this is a lighter DOM update).
To force react to exchange the items, you need to provide a key to each component.
Further explanation on react site: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children

If you could share some code, this will make it easier to understand your specific issue.

Comment: You are correct. In my case I'm not using li items, but rather have a list of `div`s inside of a parent `div`. Each of them *is* assigned a key, as they are rendered dynamically from an array using `.map`. My issue is when I change the underlying array (say, swap an array out for a completely different one), it keeps the old nodes and replaces the text inside them, and only renders the new ones. This happens despite each node having a key. I can see how this is could be useful, reusing the old nodes, but in my case it's (sometimes) the opposite of the behavior I want...

Comment: If I give the nodes a unique ID for the key, will that force it to rerender?

Comment: Are you sure you are assigning the keys in the correct react way? (there is a wrong way to do it, and then it does not work). See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children for explanation of the right and the wrong way of using keys.

Comment: I am doing it in the right way. I think the issue is I took my key usage example from another page that just uses a counter, so the keys are the same even when the array changes. I'm going to try using a unique key and will report back if that works.

Comment: Than that's the issue: then the list will still have keys 1-..., so react thinks it is the same item. If you use a completely new set of previously unused keys then you should be OK.

Comment: Yep, you're right. That works. Wow! Such a simple mistake. And I swear I took this .map example from elsewhere in the React docs.